# Multi-tenant with multi-select template SaaS Web Framework

Tags: frameworks, multi-tenant, saas, multisite

I'm looking for Frameworks that can help me implement an Application working as [Weebly](https://www.weebly.com/) or [BigCommerce](https://www.bigcommerce.com/). This mean customer can register their website, choosing their suitable template and start to operate their website. I've searched on the Internet and the results mention about the Multi-tenant and SaaS architecture; however, I'm not sure whether these keywords are what exactly I want to do or not. If i'm going wrong way please let me know how can I implement an Application like some companies I've mentioned above.Thanks!
There are some requirements:

Customers can edit their Website on the Admin Page

CMS and eCommerece, Billing should be intergrated

One source code which can generate approriate website template for customer.

Comment: There is no coding issue that we can help you with. This is an opinionated and broad question

Comment: well, i've just tried those website I've mentioned, and I have been finding how can they do this, I've read about SaaS and Multi-tenant but they are just artichecture model. Moreover, I tend to save the development cost so I'm looking for frameworks to deal with it.